# pandas rolling with varying window size

Tags: pandas, rolling-computation

I need to do a calculation on a rolling window of datapoints in a pandas dataframe, where the number of periods include in the window is different for different datapoints. While this was never supported by the rolling function it used to be possible by using a workaround with a custom indexer. I defined the following indexer:

```
class CustomIndexer(BaseIndexer):
    def get_window_bounds(self, num_values, min_periods, center, closed):
        start = np.empty(num_values, dtype=np.int64)
        end = np.empty(num_values, dtype=np.int64)
        for i in range(num_values):
            start[i] = i
            end[i] = i + self.true_window_size[i]
        return start, end
```

And then used it like this

```
IndividualValueIndexer(window_size=1,true_window_size=list_of_window_sizes)
```

I had to pass the fixed window size of 1 but I could just ignore it in the "get_window_bounds" function. This worked with pandas 1.4.1. However after updating to pandas 1.5.2 there seems to be a new function that checks if the windows returned by the "get_window_bounds" function actually match the specified window and throws an error.

Is there a good alternative to performing a rolling operation with varying window size? I tried simply looping over my data but that is more than an order of magnitude slower.